# JQuery lightSlider - How to Start on Slide 3

Tags: jquery, slider

I am trying to get the lightSlider plugin to start on a certain slide, like slide 3, for example. From what I can understand from the plug-in's [docs/website](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/settings.html) on GitHub, I can use the public function goToSlide() to make this happen. How do I do this? See my code below (fail).

**Why isn't the slider starting on slide 3?**

```
$('.slider-1UP').lightSlider({
    item:1,
    auto:false,
    loop:true
});  

$( document ).ready(function() {
    goToSlide(3);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the slider object, something like this:

```
var slider = $('.slider-1UP').lightSlider({
  item:1,
  auto:false,
  loop:true,
  pauseOnHover: true,
  pager:true,
  prevHtml: "<span class='left_V2'>&#8249;</span>",
  nextHtml: "<span class='right_V2'>&#8250;</span>",
}); 

slider.goToSlide(3)
```

Comment: Hmm.... This doesn't seem to work for me. The slider doesn't go to slide 3.... :\ Is there another way to do it?